# Cannot find any network

Tags: networking, drivers

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. I do not have built-in wi-fi module, so I am using Atheros ar5007ug adapter. I have two problems:

1. I need to replug my usb network card after every boot in order to make it visible by OS. (I am testing it via `lsusb`)
2. Even though OS sees my usb network card, it cannot find any network

What I did:

`iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp0s2f1u3  no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlxb482fe2b61bb  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Name of this network card is kind of werid.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be related to missing firmware, if device is recognized and present in the system search for a package should called firmware-atheros

Comment: I cannot find such package.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/linux-firmware/filelist is is linux-firmware, contain all of it.

Comment: I have the latest version of linux-firmware installed and it still does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: have any error or warning message from dmesg? (you can filter messages with dmesg -l err,warn)

Comment: usb 1-4: firmware version 0x4810 and device bootcode version 0x6720 differ

zd1211rw 1-4:1.0: firmware version 4725

zd1211rw 1-4:1.0: zd1211b chip 0ace:1215 v6720 high b4-82-fe MAXIM_NEW_RF pa0 g7---

IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxb482fe2b61bb: link is not ready

IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlxb482fe2b61bb: link is not ready

Comment: it seems the firmware are still missing or different on what the kernel search, have you any package called zd1211-firmware or similar?

Comment: zd1211 is an itegral part of ubuntu 16.04

Comment: also from command line is not show you any wifi ESSID?

Comment: `wlxb482fe2b61bb  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any`

Comment: can you post the result of "iwlist wlxb482fe2b61bb scan"?

Comment: `wlxb482fe2b61bb  No scan results`

Comment: I'm sorry, I run out of idea with the poor information you provide time by time, it is more guessing then analyzing. I strongly suggesting you to perform this steps: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide once you figure out what and where the problem is and is located, you could ask again a more specific question.